# Dropwizard 8.0.1 PUT returns 400

Tags: java, java-8, dropwizard

I'm getting a 400 Error on calling put on a resource :"code":400,"message":"Unable to process JSON". I'm using the embedded jetty server

I'm using postman as client for testing.

Here is the method in the resource for put method:

```
@Path("/Ads")
public class AdResource {

@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Timed
@UnitOfWork
public Response update(@Valid AdDTO adDto) {
    Ad ad = adDto.buildAd();
    ad = adDao.merge(ad);
    return Response.ok(toJson(ad)).build();
}
}
```

Here is the Json data sent from the client:

```
  {
 "id": 44,
"created": 1430927007000,
"updated": 1430927052000,
"category": "Voiture",
"type": "Berline",
"make": "AUDI",
"model": "A3",
"month": null,
"year": 2002,
"trimVersion": null,
"transmission": "Manuelle",
"fuel": "Diesel",
"door": "4 portes",
"color": "#FC809B",
"metal": true,
"warranty": true,
"publish": false,
"price": 123,
"mileage": 123,
"power": 123,
"description": "<p>df sdfds sdfsdf sdfsdfds sdfsdfsd</p>",
"adImages": [
    {
        "id": 55,
        "created": 1430926983000,
        "updated": 1430926983000,
        "name": "amine.png",
        "url": "http://localhost/assets/photo/55/photo.png",
        "photoUrl": "http://localhost/assets/ad/44/55.jpg",
        "thumbPhotoUrl": "http://localhost/assets/ad/44/55_thumb.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 54,
        "created": 1430926982000,
        "updated": 1430926982000,
        "name": "amine2.jpg",
        "url": "http://localhost/assets/photo/54/photo.jpg",
        "photoUrl": "http://localhost/assets/ad/44/54.jpg",
        "thumbPhotoUrl": "http://localhost/assets/ad/44/54_thumb.jpg"
    }
],
"options": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "13",
    "3",
    "14",
    "15"
]
}
```

The post and get methods works just fine.
I'm using dropwizard 8.0.1 java 8.

Comment: What server is this running in?  How are you sending the request?  You need to add more information to your question.

Comment: Just added more info

Comment: @MasterMind could you check and post the error stack trace from the log on your server? seems like your application trying to parse the json into your `AdDTO` but it failed for some reason.

Comment: That's right there is an exception but it's not logged : the problem is that there is an extra attribute in the object sent from the client but  the attribute does not exists in the AdDTO. Thanks @kucing_terbang

Answer (score 0):

Adding getters to all the variables of returned class solved the error for me.